# Counting words of tokenized items in DataFrame

Tags: python, list, nltk, frequency, word-count

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column that includes in each row a list of word-token. Here is the example data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'example' : pd.Series([
                            ['limited', 'edition', 'vinyl', 'disk'], 
                            ['continental', 'breakfast', 'music', 'table'],
                            ['limited', 'time', 'order']])})
```

Then I wanted to apply a simple *counter in order to inspect the frequency of words*.

**Option 1:**

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(str(df.example))
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(10), columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
rslt

    Word Frequency
0        46
1   e    13
2   i    11
3   t    10
...
```

After this didn't work properly, I managed it like this:

**Option 2:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
for source in sources:
    word_freq = defaultdict(int)
    for text in df.example:
        for word in text:
            word_freq[word] += 1 

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(word_freq, orient='index').sort_values(0, ascending=False).rename(columns={0: 'Frequency'})

            Frequency
limited     2
vinyl       1
continental 1
music       1
...
```

I wonder whether there are better methods to count pre-tokenized content, or whether **Option 1** could be fixed? Pure Python or scikit-learn based solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the best solution, but I came up with the following

```
In [3]: freq = {}
In [6]: def count_freq(word):
   ...:     for w in word:
   ...:         if w in list(freq.keys()):
   ...:             freq[w] += 1
   ...:         else:
   ...:             freq[w] = 1
   ...:

In [7]: df.example.apply(count_freq)
Out[7]:
0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: example, dtype: object

In [8]: freq
Out[8]:
{'limited': 2,
 'edition': 1,
 'vinyl': 1,
 'disk': 1,
 'continental': 1,
 'breakfast': 1,
 'music': 1,
 'table': 1,
 'time': 1,
 'order': 1}
```

Do you think it serves your purpose?